# How to make VS Code retain old project folders in sidebar like sublime?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

In sublime, when I drag a new folder into the editor, it gets added at the bottom of the list in the sidebar, but in VS Code, the old project is removed from the list on only the current project is active.

Is there any way to make VS Code sidebar hold the old projects as sublime did? (PS: I am new to VS Code)

Here is a comparison of [Sublime sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPLHb.jpg) and [VS Code sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whBXv.jpg).

EDIT: I have tried the VS Code Insiders edition, The add to workspace option kind of works, but is not the exact solution of what I was looking for. Because even if you add multiple folders to the workspace, the next time you drag and drop a folder in VS Code, The workspace will get replaced with the new folder which you opened. I want that old folder to remain in the sidebar, and the newer folder to open below it like in sublime (see the image for reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open multiple folders in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234146/open-multiple-folders-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Insiders version of vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/). There was introduces a feature called [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_preview-multi-root-workspaces). In nutshell: you can open multiple folders in 1 vscode window (drag-n-drop supported too).

Comment: You can use Insiders to get that functionality *now*, but it will be rolled out to the general release in the near future if you don't want to worry about using beta Code. They do install side-by-side though, so installing Code - Insiders will not remove your existing Code install.