# VSCode not recognizing types in sub directories

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode isn't recognizing Jest types. I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`  and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

I have installed `@types/jest` and added `jest` to the `types` field in my `tsconfig` file but it's not working.

I notice, however, it only happens for subdirectories as I have a monorepo with the following file structure:

```
 - app1
 - app2
 - app3
```

If I open only the `app1` folder, then I don't get any errors. How can I setup VSCode to work with a folder having multiple projects?

I know VSCode allow us to set up multiple workspaces but that's not what I'm looking for. Every folder has their own `node_modules` and a `tsconfig` file. I just want VSCode to recognize them for every folder rather than looking at the root level for `node_modules`.

I've also tried to create a `tsconfig` file at the root level adding this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["app1/node_modules/@types", "app2/node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open multiple Projects/Folders in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234146/open-multiple-projects-folders-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I didn't want to have multiple workspaces. I just wanted VSCode to recognize types installed from every folder instead of looking for them at the root level.

Comment: The question you asked is "How can I setup VSCode to work with a folder having multiple projects?". If this is not the question you would like answered then I would suggest you rephrase your question.

Answer (score 8):

I got a similar issue and my problem was that I was using "include"/"exclude" in my tsconfig.json, which messes with types if the file is not included or if it's excluded. Removed both options and now it works without further config.

If this is not your case, I suggest you to take a look at:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50910#issuecomment-393719145

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly why (presumably due to the way VSCode just does things), but with the following dir structure:

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── package.json
└── app2
    ├── index.ts
    ├── node_modules
    └── package.json
```

... the following seems to be the case:

1. You can eliminate all "Module not found" complaints in `app1/index.ts`, `app2/index.ts`, etc. by adding a `tsconfig.json` (even if only containing empty brackets `{}`) in your root dir.
2. You can enable intellisense in `app1/index.ts` by adding a `tsconfig.json` file  (even if only containing empty brackets `{}`) in `app1`, in `app2/index.ts` by adding a `tsconfig.json` file  (even if only containing empty brackets `{}`) in `app2`, etc.

I don't like this "solution". I'd much prefer if I could get VSCode to find the right libraries by adding something in `.vscode/settings` for the workspace rather than src files, but I don't think that's possible at the moment. I plan to submit a request to that effect to [TypeScript/issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

Comment: I have a similar file structure, but I do have a tsconfig.json in the app folders, and intellisense still does not suggest me imports from dependencies that bring their own `d.ts` types (no separate `@types` types for these dependencies). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Not sure if this has changed in recent releases, but for [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588108/why-cant-vs-code-and-typescript-find-the-assert-package) in particular, adding an empty `tsconfig.json` file at the root of my mono-repo did *not* get rid of the `module not found` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've solved your problem, I was experiencing something similar where if I had multiple projects open it wasn't recognizing jest but if I opened a single project it did see it. To fix my issue I opened my project as a multi-root workspace and it helped.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces