# New to Visual Studio Code coming from Atom (Mac) - how to have multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I'm new to VS code, and maybe I'm missing something, but in Atom there's a concept of 'add project', and all the projects are listed in the file explorer on the left.  Is this concept available in VS code, or can I only see the file explorer for one project at a time?  The only thing that looks similar is if I right click on my VS code app in my dock and I see the list of projects...but I'm feeling I'm missing something...  How do I see all added projects in the file explorer and be able to switch between them versus having it open another instance of VS code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open multiple Projects/Folders in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234146/open-multiple-projects-folders-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: search for `Multi Root Workspace`